# Blender will not start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, system

To preface, I have used Blender downloaded from blender.org on my setup quite well for a while now. I have installed it in /opt within the home location to steer around superuser constraints. OK.

Last night, I downloaded one of the recent 2.8 test builds and while figuring out the interface Blender completely locked up. Not only did Blender lock up, the computer locked up, too. There was no signs of the CPU taking on any additional stress. Fans not spinning up or anything like that.

After a hard reset, the computer runs fine, but Blender will no longer start. This includes the 2.79 build that's installed. No errors, Taskmanager listing, no response. Attempting to uninstall Blender gives errors that all the files are write-locked. After going into superuser levels, I could get it removed and reinstalled, but no improvements.

In short, I don't know how I broke it but I'm hoping someone has advice to help me get this working again.

Thanks all!

Comment: OK! I found some more details through the terminal:

I attempted manually executing via the terminal. This is the response:

Read prefs: /home/****/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend
/home/sources/blender-release/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:198: X11 glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty! Looks like somewhere the amdgpu-pro drivers were breaking. I uninstalled them, ran 'apt-get autoremove' then rebooted the system. Blender's working again on the built-in drivers.